# Alt+F2 to run terminal fails to do anything

Tags: command-line, root

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, 
I type:

```
sudo Terminal
```

But nothing happens.  I am not aware of making any changes and this used to work.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

This should open a terminal session.

If you want to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, the command to open the terminal is `gnome-terminal`.

You can either use the `sudo` command for actions that require root or you can use the `su` and then enter the root password to run the session as root. Alternatively, you can use `sudo -i` to run a root shell.

If you don't know the root password, use `sudo passwd root` to change it.

Answer (score 1):

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to run Terminal

When you are in Terminal, you type sudo before a command if it requires root privileges.